# Clang++ fails while creating APK with Buildozer on MacMojave

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I use Buildozer and Python3.6/7 on Mac OS Mojave (10.14.5) and run the following command to create an APK:

```
    buildozer -v android debug
```

I get the following error:

```
    clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make: *** [/Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so] Error 1
```

The error occurs due to the following statement:

```
    /Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -Wl,-soname,libmain.so -shared --sysroot=/Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main/__/__/SDL/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.o /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main/start.o -lgcc -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -latomic -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so  -gcc-toolchain /Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 -no-canonical-prefixes -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -L/Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings   -L/Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog -lpython3.7m -lstdc++ -lc -lm -o /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
```

The error is similar to this problem https://github.com/mateidavid/nanocall/issues/8 but could not be solved based on the suggestions.

Full log:

```
    buildozer -v android debug
    # Check configuration tokens
    # Ensure build layout
    # Check configuration tokens
    # Preparing build
    # Check requirements for android
    # Search for Git (git)
    #  -> found at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/bin/git
    # Search for Cython (cython)
    #  -> found at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/cython
    # Search for Java compiler (javac)
    #  -> found at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac
    # Search for Java keytool (keytool)
    #  -> found at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/keytool
    # Install platform
    # Run '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
    # Cwd None
    You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    # Apache ANT found at /Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
    # Android SDK found at /Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
    # Android NDK found at /Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
    # Check application requirements
    # Check garden requirements
    # Compile platform
    # Run '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21'
    # Cwd /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py:84: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import imp
    [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
    [INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27)
    [INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
    [INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
    [INFO]:    Found NDK revision 17.2.4988734
    [INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
    [INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenv
    [INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
    [INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
    [INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
    [WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
    [INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
    [INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
    [INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
    [INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
    [INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
    [INFO]:    Dist will have name myapp and requirements (python3, kivy)
    [INFO]:    Dist contains the following requirements as recipes: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
    [INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules () installed from pip
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
    [INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
    [INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 70 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython3
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
    [INFO]:    hostpython3 download already cached, skipping                       
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading libffi
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 65 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/libffi
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/lib...(and 32 more)
    [INFO]:    libffi download already cached, skipping                            
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading openssl
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 66 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/openssl
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.or...(and 29 more)
    [INFO]:    openssl download already cached, skipping                           
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 69 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
    [INFO]:    sdl2_image download already cached, skipping                        
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 69 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
    [INFO]:    sdl2_mixer download already cached, skipping                        
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 67 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 48 more)
    [INFO]:    sdl2_ttf download already cached, skipping                          
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading sqlite3
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 66 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sqlite3
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org...(and 37 more)
    [INFO]:    sqlite3 download already cached, skipping                           
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading python3
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 66 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python3
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
    [INFO]:    python3 download already cached, skipping                           
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 63 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 26 more)
    [INFO]:    sdl2 download already cached, skipping                              
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading six
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 62 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.or...(and 41 more)
    [INFO]:    six download already cached, skipping                               
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 66 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 29 more)
    [INFO]:    pyjnius download already cached, skipping                           
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Downloading android
    [INFO]:    Skipping android download as no URL is set
    [INFO]:    Downloading kivy
    [INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/oliver/Desktop...(and 63 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 25 more)
    [INFO]:    kivy download already cached, skipping                              
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
    [INFO]:    Unpacking hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop
    [INFO]:    hostpython3 is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking libffi for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/lib...(and 32 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
    [INFO]:    libffi is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking openssl for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.or...(and 29 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/openssl/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
    [INFO]:    openssl is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
    [INFO]:    sdl2_image is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
    [INFO]:    sdl2_mixer is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 48 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
    [INFO]:    sdl2_ttf is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org...(and 37 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
    [INFO]:    sqlite3 is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking python3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
    [INFO]:    python3 is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 26 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
    [INFO]:    sdl2 is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking six for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.or...(and 41 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/six-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
    [INFO]:    six is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Unpacking pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 29 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
    [INFO]:    pyjnius is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    -> running rm -rf /Users/oliver/Desktop/T...(and 122 more)
    [INFO]:    -> running cp -a /Users/oliver/Desktop/Tr...(and 242 more)
    [INFO]:    Unpacking kivy for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 25 more)
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/kivy-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
    [INFO]:    kivy is already unpacked, skipping
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    # Prebuilding recipes
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    hostpython3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding libffi for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    libffi has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for libffi[armeabi-v7a]
    [INFO]:    libffi already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding openssl for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    openssl has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    sdl2_image has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_image[armeabi-v7a]
    [INFO]:    sdl2_image already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    sdl2_mixer has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_mixer[armeabi-v7a]
    [INFO]:    sdl2_mixer already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    sdl2_ttf has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    sqlite3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding python3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    python3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for python3[armeabi-v7a]
    [INFO]:    python3 already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    sdl2 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding six for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    six has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    pyjnius has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for pyjnius[armeabi-v7a]
    [INFO]:    pyjnius already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding android for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    android has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/android-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding kivy for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    kivy has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
    [INFO]:    # Building recipes
    [INFO]:    Building hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    Skipping hostpython3 (3.7.1) build, as it has already been completed
    [INFO]:    Building libffi for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    libffi said it is already built, skipping
    [INFO]:    Building openssl for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    openssl said it is already built, skipping
    [INFO]:    Building sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    Building sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    Building sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    Building sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    sqlite3 said it is already built, skipping
    [INFO]:    Building python3 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build
    [WARNING]: Doing some hacky stuff to link properly
    [INFO]:    -> running cp /Users/oliver/.buildozer/an...(and 86 more)
    [INFO]:    -> running cp /Users/oliver/.buildozer/an...(and 84 more)
    [WARNING]: lld not found, linking without it. Consider installing lld if linker errors occur.
    [INFO]:    Activating flags for sqlite3
    [INFO]:    Activating flags for libffi
    [INFO]:    Activating flags for openssl
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Building sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
    [INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1
               working: make: *** [/Users/oliver/Desktop/Translat...(and 118 more) Exception in thread background thread for pid 6210:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /Users/oliver/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/ndk-build V=1

  STDOUT:
[here are about 5000 lines i excluded]
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/Users/oliver/Desktop/TranslationApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Please post  the full log.

Comment: hi , did you find a solution ? i am  getting  the same error